# Emulating UIAlertView with voiceover: making the correct sound

Tags: ios, accessibility, uialertview, voiceover

I've decided to make a class that emulates the functionality of `UIAlertView` so that I can have a better API for callbacks and theme the alerts better. I add another window to the iOS main window to show the alert.

The problem is with voiceover. With the standard `UIAlertView` voiceover makes a special sound to indicate that there is an alert view on the screen.

I can get the standard voiceover screen change chirp by posting `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` but this is different from the Alert view's chirp.

I want this to feel like a `UIAlertView` for voiceover users. To do this i need to be able to programatically replicate its special chirp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal (you'd lose the theming for instance), but you could have your custom implementation detect if voiceover is enabled using `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` and fall back to using a standard `UIAlertView` if it is.

Comment: You know thats not a bad idea at all. With the alert replacement acting as `UIAlertViewDelegate` I can still have the completion block callbacks. Worth it as voice over customers tend to be the nicest customers.